# Splitting a string upon matching a specific criteria

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to split a string by the first vowel. If the following letter is also a vowel, then it must not split until it has reached the last vowel in the sequence. Examples are:

- `"Auxiliary"` => `["Au" "xiliary"]`
- `"Doorknob"` => `["Doo" "rknob"]`
- `"Green"` => `["Gree" "n"]`

I did:

```
"Auxiliary".split("u")
# => ["A", "uxiliary"]
```

I need to split after the match, not before. I am not sure if I could do something like `"Auxiliary".split(/[aeiouAEIOU]/)`; this would only split the first time it finds a vowel.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: `"Auxillary".split(/([aeiou]{2})/i).partition.with_index {|_,i| i<=1 }.map(&:join) #=> ["Au", "xillary"]` is one way, not very neat but seems to work.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Depending on the exact requirements (and the version of Ruby being used), a lookaround might also make sense, e.g. `(?<=[aeiou])`.

Comment: Ruby Version: 2.3.0
& thanks for the suggestion sagarpandya2, all help is appreciated! However, I've actually gone with Tim's answer below, which works perfectly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh yes I see now, you mean something like `"Auxillary".split(/(?<=[aeiou]{2})/i) #=> ["Au", "xillary"]`, works great. @IainK no worries, Tim's answer is great and he pretty much gave the answer in this comment too.

Comment: I first thought a lookaround would be helpful, but I'm now doubtful about that. I'd like to write `str.split(/(?<=\A[^aeiou'*[aeiou]+)/)` but Ruby does not support variable-length positive lookbehinds, so that won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the following pattern:

```
([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)(.*)

([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)    match and capture zero or more continuous non vowels
                       followed by one or more vowels
(.*)                   then capture the remainder of the string  

puts "Auxiliary".scan(/([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)(.*)/i)
puts "Doorknob".scan(/([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)(.*)/i)
puts "Green".scan(/([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)(.*)/i)
```

**Output:**

```
Au
xiliary
Doo
rknob
Gree
n
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Nice, refactor suggestion: `scan(/([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)(.*)/i)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, but I think that would require Ruby `1.9` or later.

Comment: I'm using Ruby version 2.3.0.
Oh, and thanks for the answer Tim, this worked perfectly. :) I really appreciate the explanation, too!

Comment: A small thing: for `R = /([^aeiou]*[aeiou]+)(.*)/i`, `"ba".scan(R) #=> [["ba", ""]]` and  `"bb".scan(R) #=> []`. It may be more useful to write `"ba".scan(R).first&.reject { |a| a.empty? } #=> ["ba"]; "bb".scan(R).first&.reject { |a| a.empty? } #=> nil`. `&` in `first&` is Ruby's [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). (btw, I accidentally deleted my earlier comment.)

Answer (score 2):

```
R = /
    \A        # match beginning of string
    [^aeiou]* # match zero or more non-vowels
    [aeiou]+  # match one or more vowels
    /ix       # case-indifferent and free-spacing regex definition modes

def split_after_vowels(str)
  return nil unless str =~ R
  i = Regexp.last_match.end(0)
  [str[0,i], str[i..-1]] 
end

split_after_vowels 'Aardvark'
  #=> ["Aa", "rdvark"] 
split_after_vowels 'taught'
  #=> ["tau", "ght"] 
split_after_vowels 'zzzzzz'
  #=> nil 
split_after_vowels 'zzzzzz sleep'
  #=> ["zzzzzz slee", "p"]
```